# Multiple Grid Reordering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to reorder my grid in a special way. This is my base stack on mobile:

```
A
B
C
D
```

On Breakpoint `sm` I want this order:

```
A   C
B   D
```

On Breakpoint `md` the order should be:

```
B   A   D
    C
```

where `C` should be exactly beyond `A` no matter how the height `B` or `D` is.

I tried some pushing and pulling on JSBin http://jsbin.com/gitawaveso/1 but that seems not to be the way it works.

Any solutions to this?

Comment: Push and pull only work horizontally. You can't use Bootstrap's css for this. You can use flexbox (css) or jQuery or server side detection and serve up different html for the different devices. Or you can hide and show with the responsive utilities.

Answer (score 0):

On sm breakpoint try to use this :

```
A class=" col-sm-6 "
B class=" col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6"
C class=" col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6"
D class=" col-sm-6 "
```

On md breakpoint:

```
A class=" col-md-4 col-md-push-4"
B class=" col-md-4 col-md-pull-4"
C class=" col-md-4 col-md-push-4"
D class=" col-md-4 col-md-pull-4"
```